# Bash get text between 5th and 6th underscore in a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable called `$folder_name` which contains the string

```
Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test
```

which is the name of a folder.
I'm trying to extract `PJ6678` from the folder name.
I know the folder name will put the user id (the text I need) between the 5th and 6th underscore, I don't know what text/symbols will be present after the 6th underscore.

I'm using Bash script, i'd really appreciate the help if someone could help with this functionality as i'm completely lost trying to use sed (after reading for hours i'm assuming this is the correct tool for the job?

Comment: Use [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) with delimeter set to `_`. You can do it with `sed`, but if it's always between 5th and 6th underscore, then just `cut` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Bash only solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test"
IFS='_' read -ra IN <<< "$INPUT"
echo ${IN[5]}
```

Or use cut:

```
cut -d '_' -f 6 <<< "Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test"
```

Or use awk:

```
awk -F "_" '{ print $6 }' <<< "Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, really appreciate it. 
cut -d '_' -f 6 <<< "Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test" worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

If you want pure-bash solution, you can use tokenize the file name, and pick up the 5th element

```
IFS=_ read -a token <<< "$folder_name"
id=${token[5]}
```

Eliminating dependency and performance hit from launching additional programs per folder name.

Comment: @stephanmg - no harm intended, it happens a lot, especially on newly posted questions

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quiet sure what's the policy. Should one delete a similiar answer?

Comment: @stephanmg I'm not sure it's worth the time on this ticket. It will only matter for 'high-traffic tickets'.

Comment: I'll delete my own near duplicates if I post it more than a couple of minutes after the first. Basically, I ask myself "Did I really not have the opportunity to see the first answer before I posted my own?" and try to use my best judgement. If I see two nearly identical answers, I'll likewise upvote both (as I've done here) if they are no more than a couple of minutes apart; otherwise, I only upvote the first one (but don't penalize the late answer, though if it is particularly later, I might comment on its status as a duplicate).

Comment: I will try to follow this procedure @chepner as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
echo $a | awk -F'_'  '{print $6}'
```

Here, `_` is the delimiter and `$a` is a variable that holds the value.

Comment: what does it mean ?@stephanmg

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's a pure-shell solution that doesn't rely on `bash` extensions like arrays.

```
$ folder_name=Release_2019_Config_V6_Standalone_PJ6678_Test
$ tmp=${folder_name#*_*_*_*_*_}  # Because we know how many _ to strip
$ echo ${tmp%_*}
PJ6678
```

Because the `#` operator strips the *shortest* prefix, this won't allow `*` to match any `_` itself; if it did, we could shorten the prefix by making the underscore match one of the literal `_` in the pattern instead.

Comment: That's a neat trick! Thanks for posting this. (I was aware of the # and % operators but didn't think to combine them in this way). +1!